# How can we identify the quotient group $GL(n,\mathbb{R})/SL(n,\mathbb{R})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

How can we identify the quotient group  $GL(n,\mathbb{R})/SL(n,\mathbb{R})$

I am using First isomorphisam theorem,but i am not getting the solution
how can we find out the right hand side set of the mapping and kernel

Comment: Is $SL(n,R)$ a normal subgroup of $GL(n,R)$? If you want to use the first isomorphism theorem you should constract a homomorphism $\phi: GL(n,R) \to G$ where $\phi^{-1}(1) = SL(n,R)$ in which case $SL$ will be a normal subgroup of $GL$.

Comment: @flawr Yes. $\det(AMA^{-1})=\det(AA^{-1})\det(M)=\det(M)=1$ if $M\in SL(n,\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: My question was directed at OP as a hint. I think you could expand your comment to an answer?

Answer (score 5):

Consider the map $\det:GL(n,\mathbb{R})\to\mathbb{R}^{\ast}$, where $\mathbb{R}^{\ast}$ is the multiplicative group of nonzero real numbers. This is a homomorphism, its kernel is $SL(n,\mathbb{R})$, and it is surjective.